# How to stop jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, animation

I want to use little help box on my site, animated by Jquery. everything is ok, but when I quickly go in and out of box, it start showing ang hiding like crazy. Is there any way how to stop function hiding box? 
Here is my help box: http://jojo.i-web.sk/test/box.php

this is code:

```
<body>
    <center>!!LOOK AT DOWN RIGHT CORNER!!</center>
    <div id="help-box">
        <div id="help_sipka">
            <<
        </div>
        <div id="help_problem_nadpis">
            <h1>Do you have problem?</h1>
            Click here.
        </div>
        <div id="help_problem_button">
            <div style="float:right;"><acronym title="Zatvoriť"><input id="help_zavri" class="button_zavri" type="button" value="X"></acronym></div>
            <h1>Do you have problem?</h1>
            Have you lost password or found bug? Do you need help<br>
            We can help you.<br>
            Send mail to our admins.<br>
            <input class="button_odosli" type="button" name="posli_mail" value="Send mail">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        var help_finished=1;

            $('#help-box').mouseenter(function(){
                if(help_finished!=2) {
                    help_finished=1;
                    $('#help-box').animate({width:'200'});
                    $('#help_sipka').delay(500).slideUp();        
                    $('#help_problem_nadpis').delay(500).slideDown();
                }
            });

            $('#help-box').mouseleave(function(){ 
                if (help_finished ==1) {
                    setTimeout(hide_box, 500);
                    help_finished=0;
                }
            });

            function hide_box() {
                if (help_finished==0||help_finished==3) {
                    $('#help_sipka').slideDown();        
                    $('#help_problem_nadpis').slideUp();
                    $('#help-box').delay(300).animate({width:'30'});
                }  
            }

            $('#help_zavri').click(function(){
                help_finished=3
                $('#help_problem_button').slideUp();
                $('#help-box').animate({opacity:'0.75'});
                hide_box();        
            });

            $('#help-box').click(function(){
                if(help_finished!=3) {
                    help_finished=2;
                    $('#help-box').animate({opacity:'1'});
                    $('#help_problem_button').slideDown(); 
                    $('#help_problem_nadpis').slideUp(); 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `$('#help-box').stop(true, true).animate({width:'200'});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jquery [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method:

```
// Will stop the current animation and then start a fadeout.
$(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
```

So in your example, you might want to do this:

```
$('#help-box').stop(true,true).animate({width:'200'});
```

Also, you can look firing the next animation after the previous by using the finished delegate, so you don't need to hardcode delays:

```
$('#help-box').stop(true,true).animate({width:'200'}, function () {
        $('#help_sipka').slideUp(function () {
           $('#help_problem_nadpis').slideDown();
        }); 
 });
```

Since you are using timeouts, you will need to keep that around in a variable and clear it, using [clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) before you set a new timeout function:

```
// keep this variable scoped outside the method call.
var timeout;

//... Whenever you set the timeout, clear it before you set a new one.
clearTimeout(timeout);
timeout = setTimeout(hide_box, 500);
```

Comment: problem is that when I leave helpbox, I call setTimeout(hide_box, 500)...then I enter and leave and again I call setTimeout(hide_box, 500) over and over, even if the first one function isn't over...so it isn't animation I need to stop but. I have to stop calling function hide_box until the frist on is over. But I dont know how.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's `.stop()`.

When you start a new animation you can do this.

```
$('selector').stop(true, true).animate({});
```

`stop()` with those parameters clears jQuery's animation queue and forces the current animation to stop, allowing the the proceeding animation to start immediately.

**[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
$(this).stop(true);
```

jQuery .stop() docs - http://api.jquery.com/stop/